# socket.io origin set but anyways getting errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, socket.io

i'm making a website for a school project where there is a live updating table with data about how many rounds player have ran.
It's almost done, but i'm getting one error, i can't solve:

```
ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://creeperhd.de:8443/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O88eQ0_' from origin 'https://creeperhd.de' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I already have this in my server code to prevent this error:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(http,{cors:{origin:"*"}});
```

But i anyways get the same error...

Can somebody tell what i can do?

Comment: Do you also have the CORS package installed on your server?  If so, please show that code.  If not, then the `cors` options for socket.io won't do anything on their own.

Comment: oh i guess here we have the issue beacause i didn't install it, how do i install and use it?

Comment: You can start by reading: https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/

Comment: If you control the client-side of the socket.io connection, you can also remove CORS issues entirely by adding `{transports: ['websocket']}` as a connect option in the client.  This will skip the socket.io default http polling phase of connection and avoid all CORS issues.  See doc for `transports` option [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#transports).

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'wss://creeperhd.de:8443/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Comment: maybe that's because the website uses httpS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
i just forgot to tell the server to use the ssl certificates :/
[How to do it](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33099148)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do one of two things to either enable CORS support or bypass CORS restrictions.

**Option #1:** Change the client-side to skip socket.io http polling by changing the client-side connection code to add an option like this:

```
const socket = io("https://example.com", {
  transports: ["websocket"] // use webSocket only
});
```

It is the initial socket.io http polling that trips up on CORs restrictions.  If you skip that and go straight to a webSocket connection, then webSocket connections are not limited by CORs so you won't run into CORs access issues.

**Option #2:**  Install the CORS package on your http server and configure it appropriately to enable CORS access for your socket.io endpoint.  The CORs page is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).  The socket.io doc for enabling CORS access is [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/).

The `cors` options shown for socket.io depend upon the CORS package being installed on your web server.  So, you have to use both of these together or implement your own custom CORs handling to fully enable CORs access.

Comment: Option #2 almost did it!
But now i get the a error that the connection to wss://<my domain:port> failed.
I guess that's because the website uses https do you know by any change how to solve that?

Comment: @HackerHK - We don't know your site configuration and can't see any of the relevant client connection code and web server code to help you debug.